# Rails + Angular Token Authorization via Oauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, authentication, oauth, devise

I'm using a Rails backend (API scoped to '/api') with an Angular frontend. I'm trying to incorporate token based authorization using ng-token-auth and devise-token-auth.

I got the login working using regular registration, but I can't seem to get it working with oAuth. I also don't understand how to debug the issue.

I have a Github App set up with secret / key. On my front end, there's a button that will use ng-token-auth built in $auth.authenticate('github').

What happens is the page will redirect to github, ask for permission, and then redirect back to my website (new tab though, not the original tab) and load the homepage.

The auth didn't actually do anything and no user is set. I've checked all the routes, callback urls, and followed all the instructions on https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth and https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth but I can't figure out what's going wrong or how to diagnose it.

An error I do get if i Log the $auth.authenticate response is that the auth is invalid ("user cancelled login") but this seems to be more of a timeout thing than anything?

Is there a way to see if any token is actually being sent in the header? What are potential problems? I've tried Twitter as well

```
(setting the host to either http://127.0.0.1:3000 or http://localhost:3000)
```

Edit: this is what the http requests look like in terminal

```
Started GET "/omniauth/github?     auth_origin_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fsign_in&favorite_color=blue&resource_class=User" for      127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-29 18:33:55 -0800
I, [2014-12-29T18:33:55.295507 #46466]  INFO -- omniauth: (github) Request phase initiated.


Started GET "/omniauth/github/callback?code=3c03dbb28c2bb0bc8d36&state=5ce4e8bae5f9671ffe521ceeb54a14eb42c3b2866cd79b8e" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-29 18:33:55 -0800
I, [2014-12-29T18:33:55.692405 #46466]  INFO -- omniauth: (github) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"code"=>"3c03dbb28c2bb0bc8d36", "state"=>"5ce4e8bae5f9671ffe521ceeb54a14eb42c3b2866cd79b8e"}
Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 117ms (Views: 116.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Edit:

Okay, so I got it to work. Kind of. My rails routes file had this line:

```
  root to: "home#index", anchor: false
```

I removed the "anchor: false" and the callback for omniauth now successfully works. However, this makes it so the rails/angular routes don't work 100% / play nice. for example, if i go to localhost:3000 and then click a link to /sign_in, it will go to the correct page. if I try to go to localhost:3000/sign_in directly in the browser, rails will complain about a missing route...

Okay Solved!

So I just recreated the callback route in the rails routes file and it worked. 
    get "/omniauth/:provider/callback" => "devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#redirect_callbacks"

When I checked rails routes earlier, it had that exact route but it was after the root route was defined. I don't know how to fix it without explicitly defining it in the rails routes.

Comment: You can answer your own question. Would be a good idea if you solved it :)